# UIScrollview not visible in iPad Xcode 7.3 iOS 10.0.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, ios-autolayout

UIScrollView is visible and working on iPhone 4,5,6. But not visible in iPad.

The hierarchy of views in viewController is given below:

```
CameraViewController
    FirstView
    SecondView
    CameraSettingsView
        ScrollView
            ContainerView
                 View
    FourthView
```

I have set up constraints to align ScrollView to top,bottom, leading and trailing to CameraSettingsView, set Scrollview.height and Scrollview.width to the height and width of CameraSettingView respectively.

Again, I have aligned ContainerView to top, bottom, leading and trailing to the scrollview and set up height and width equal to the height and width to scrollView.

This appears correctly to iPhone 4,5,6. In iPad it only appears the CameraSettingsView, but does not appear scrollview or any other view under scrollview.

**Note: I have copied Device Support file for iOS 10.0, 10.1 and 10.2 from Xcode 8.2.1**

Comment: please provide ios & xcode verions, as well

Comment: Provide your code where you set the heights and widths...

Comment: I have set the heights and widths using constraints. ScrollView heights and weights is equal to CameraSettingsView and ContainerView heights and weights is equal to Scrollview.